# How can i authorized a user against SAML Assertion coming from Identity server(Wso2is 5.4.0)

Tags: spring-security, authorization, spring-saml, wso2-identity-server

i am using Spring SAML2.O and WSO2IS::

After successfully authentication in IDP its send a saml assertion(carry all the information of the User like username, roles and etc.) as part of response to service provider.

Here what i want is, i want to authorized the user on the basis of ROLES. SO  how can i fetch the role of the user from saml assertion and authorized and give the access permission into my service provider.

here is my SAML Assertion:-

Your help is going to save me.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If want to do authorization through WSO2IS, it's already baked in, though there are a couple ways to approach it depending on your needs. As a general answer, you probably want to review [Post Authentication Handlers](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Post-authentication+Handlers+in+Identity+Server).

You don't necessarily need to write your own handler though. You mentioned wanting to read the role from a SAML assertion, but if you just want to do basic authorization by role, why not let WSO2 check it for you? You can apply an [XACML policy](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Access+Control+and+Entitlement+Management) by [enabling authorization on the service provider](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Configuring+Access+Control+Policy+for+a+Service+Provider) under Local and Outbound Authentication in the IS.

If none of those options work for you, you can still manage authorization by [using REST calls](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Fine-grained+Authorization+using+XACML+Requests+in+JSON+Format) to the PDP.